# Compute pairwise differences of nested lists

Tags: clojure

I have a list of lists composed by the following items (columns are 5, always):

```
(   
 (1 3 2 4 5)   
 (2 5 1 3 1)   
 (0 8 1 2 2)  
 ...  
)
```

and I want to obtain another list where

- each item is a list
- the ith item in the nth sublist is the difference between the ith items of the nth  and (n + 1)th sublists of the original input.

In the example above the result would be:

```
(   
 (-1 -2 1 1 4)   
 (2 -3 0 1 -1)  
 ... 
)
```

The first list (-1 -2 1 1 4) is the result of taking the first and second list in the original input

(1 3 2 4 5)
(2 5 1 3 1)

and then subtracting the element with the same index

( 1-2 3-5 2-1 4-3 5-1)

and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work with pairs of adjacent elements, you can pass `map` two collections: the original collection, and an offset version of itself:

```
(defn diffs [xs]
  (map #(map - % %2) xs (rest xs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

amalloy beat me to it, but since I already started here is a version using reduce. It's overly complicated due to the amount of information we have to keep in the accumulator:

```
(first ; we are only interested in the accumulator, hence the outer 'first'
 (reduce (fn [[acc prev] curr] [(conj acc (mapv - prev curr)) curr])
  [[] (first test)] 
  (rest test)))
```

And a cleaner version which is basically the same as amalloy's answer above (I like his more).

```
(map (fn [[v1 v2]] (map - v1 v2)) 
     (partition 2 1 test))
```